# Sitecore TDS Deployment __Standard Values

Tags: sitecore, tds

I'm running into an issue with Hedgehog's TDS - I have some presentation details specified on my Base Page template.  The presentation details reside in the __Renderings field of __Standard Values.  I've set the item to "Deploy Once", but it appears that Sitecore ignores that setting on __Standard Values with the package deployment (UpdateInstallationWizard).  If I update any of the presentation details on the production site, they are lost with my next deployment.

For now I've excluded the item from my production build - but it's kind of a pain.

I've opened a ticket with Hedgehog - they say it's a Sitecore problem.  I opened a ticket with Sitecore - they say that UpdateInstallationWizard wasn't meant for use outside of sitecore.

Is there a good way to get around this?  Should I not be specifying any presentation details in a base template?

Comment: You should. But its not customary that these settings get updated in the live environment. Normally, only /sitecore/content updates in the CM. And Media Library, of course.

Comment: What sitecore and TDS versions are you using?

Comment: Sorry - that would probably be helpful.  TDS 5.1.0.0 and Sitecore 7.5 (rev. 141003)

Comment: My suggestion will be keep all templates property as "DeployAlways" so any field changes and presentation changes will be always included in UpdateInstallationWizard.

Comment: Recommend having a Master.TDS.proj and a Master.Content.TDS.proj project to split up the things that you know only developers will change (IE. Templates, sublayouts, placeholders and system stuff - if any). That way you can have the Master.TDS project always deploy as you know everything in there is safe to go up, whilst the content project can be excluded once there is real content in there..

Comment: @goose I already have that project setup - this is a standard values item under a template - the problem is that __Renderings on a standard value might need to be modified by authors

Comment: Hmm that's not really something that you should be letting authors do (in my opinion) especially because of TDS as you've described. I would be telling my authors to duplicate pages with the values they want, or to request devs to update std_values for them.

Comment: That was my predicament - it's not user friendly anyway.  Unfortunately - other than having a hard-coded menu, there isn't another way.  SCORE fixes the problem with cascading placeholders - but it looks like I'll be using a spider for my next menu.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue just today. The only solution I can offer is to manually delete the previous __StandardValues and then rerun the update installation wizard.